# Subspace in $\Bbb R^n$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let  $n_1$,...,$n_k$  be vectors ∈ $\mathbb{R}^n$ for given $k$  ∈ $\mathbb{N}$. Show that
>
> $$U_k:= \{x ∈ \mathbb{R^n}: \forall i ∈\{1,\dots,k\},\langle n_i,x\rangle=0\} $$
>   is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

Can someone check if my proof is right ?

> 1) Let $n$ be the zero vector, then <$0$,$x$>=$0$ ∈ $U_k$
>
> 2) Let $n_2$ and $x_2$ be also two vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that <$n_2$,$x_2$>=$0$  ,
>
> then <$n$,$x$> + <$n_2$,$x_2$>= $0$+$0$  ∈ $U_k$
>
> 3) Let $c$ be a scalar  ∈ $\mathbb{R}$, then  $c$.<$n$,$x$>= $c$.$0$ ∈ $U_k$

So $U_k$ is a subspace

Comment: Your definition of $U_k$ refers to $U_k$, and you probably meant to end the question with "is a vector (sub)space"

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: You didn't quite understand me, so I have made some (hopefully correct) edits. If you don't agree with the new phrasing, please change it to the correct one. In future you can refer to this link to type math nicely https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) is fine but 2),3) are not. Here is how to do it correctly.

2) Take $x_1,x_2\in U_k$. then you need to show that $x_1+x_2\in U_k$, i.e. that $\langle n_i,x_1+x_2\rangle =0$ for all $i$. But since $x_1,x_2\in U_k$, $$\langle n_i,x_1+x_2\rangle=\langle n_i,x_1\rangle+\langle n_i,x_2\rangle=0+0=0,$$ this follows. (The only thing we used here was linearity of the scalar product!)

For 3), take a scalar $\lambda$ and a vector $x\in U_k$. You then need to show that $\langle n_i\lambda x\rangle=0$ holds for all $i$. Using linearity of the scalar product again, $$\langle n_i,\lambda x\rangle=\lambda \langle n_i,x\rangle =0,$$ since $x\in U_k$.